# Different espresso tests for different devices

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an app with different layouts - for tablets, normal portrait and small. How can I write and execute different test suites for each device type ?

Comment: Hope my answer helped. Did you find a different solution?

Answer (score 2):

Annotating your tests with conditions that must evaluate to true in order to run is one way to do it. The repository [Android Test Rules](https://github.com/shazam/androidTestRules) helps you do it like this:

```
@Test
@IgnoreWhen(device = Form.Tablet.class)
public void phoneCanMakeACall() {
    // Run test that only applies to phones.
}
```

Just follow the steps in the README. Those steps also show you how to create more conditions to add to the ones [already provided](https://github.com/shazam/androidTestRules/tree/master/src/main/java/com/shazam/android/test/conditions).

Notes:

- I am using it in a small project and I can confirm that it works as expected.
- Since using the `@IgnoreWhen` annotation more than once for a test method is not possible, I haven't yet figured out how to combine my custom conditions with the ones already provided without copying and pasting their logic into my code.

Comment: That library is pretty neat! Also it's very small, I think one could also just implement a custom rule easily following their code without the need for a new dependency

Comment: Yes, that's true.